# jQuery append title tag from one div to another div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab the title attribute from a div called .swatch.selected and move it into a new div I created called .variationTitle. I had to add .variationTitle via jQuery append as well.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_foundation-shades">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-vanilla " title="Vanilla" data-value="vanilla">
    <img src="image tag here" alt="Vanilla">
  </span>
<div class="variationTitle"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".tawcvs-swatches" ).append( "<div class='variationTitle'></div>" );
```

When you click on the span image, a class of selected gets added automatically to the span tag.

Comment: so on which clck you want to append that title? span image click?

Comment: Where's `.swatch.selected`?

Comment: yes, when you click on span.swatch the title of that span gets displayed in .variationTitle

Comment: a class of .selected automatically gets added when you click on span.swatch. that's part of the default functionality.

Comment: Are you trying to make the title of `variationTitle` the same as your `.swatch.selected` or are you trying to have it display as text to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Get the title from the `title` attribute.  Put a listener on the image to put the text in when clicked.

```js
var title = $('.swatch-vanilla').attr('title');

$('img').on('click', function() {
  $('.variationTitle').text(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_foundation-shades">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-vanilla " title="Vanilla" data-value="vanilla">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Vanilla" alt="Vanilla">
  </span>
<div class="variationTitle"></div>
</div>
```

The above would work for the particular example, but you could make it more robust:

```js
$('.swatch').on('click', function() {
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  $(this).siblings('.variationTitle').text(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_foundation-shades">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-vanilla " title="Vanilla" data-value="vanilla">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Vanilla" alt="Vanilla">
  </span>
<div class="variationTitle"></div>
</div>
<div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_foundation-shades">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-chocolate " title="Chocolate" data-value="vanilla">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Chocolate" alt="Chocolate">
  </span>
<div class="variationTitle"></div>
</div>
<div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_foundation-shades">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-peach " title="Peach" data-value="vanilla">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Peach" alt="Peach">
  </span>
<div class="variationTitle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/hHLXr/364/

```
$('.swatch').click(function() {
    var text = $(".swatch").attr("title");
    $('.variationTitle').text(text);
});
```

You basically get the value of the attribute and set the text of the next element to be that value. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Almost...same problem as above. There are multiple swatches. So only first shows up.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it,

i did a quick draft on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttpzaco7/)

```
$( ".tawcvs-swatches" ).append( "<div class='variationTitle'></div>" );

$('span.swatch').on('click',function(){
  $(this).siblings('.variationTitle').html($(this).attr('title'));
})
```